# Hide div on page but div shows before being hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I get the `<div>` not to show at all when the page loads? The div is set to hidden in JS and the `<div>` hides but its after the `<div>` has already shown on the page for a brief second.

I am using this popup in my website.
http://mootools.net/forge/p/popupwindow

Here is my code :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    App = {};
    window.addEvent('domready', function() {
        App.popUp1 = new PopUpWindow('', { contentDiv: 'trailerquestion', width: 559 });
                App.popUp2 = new PopUpWindow('', { contentDiv: 'popup-redflag', width: 559 });

    });

</script>
<?php 
function JSLink($text, $onclick) {
    return "<a href=\"JavaScript:void(0);\" onclick=\"$onclick\">$text</a>";
}
 $asklink=JSLink('<div class="buttonNew greenB bigrounded trailer-button-question"><span>Ask me a question</span></div>', 'App.popUp1.open(); App.popUp1.positionTo(this, 1180, 100);');

 ?>

 <?php
                                echo $asklink;
                            ?>
                            <div id="trailerquestion">
                                <?php     
                                    $this->load->view('popup/popupaskmequestion',$results);
                                ?>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Which div do you want to hide? #trailerquestion or the one with class="buttonNew greenB bigrounded trailer-button-question"

Answer (score 6):

Set the div's display to none with CSS, not Javascript. Then change the display property with Javascript when you want it to be shown.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the div to just be hidden but take up the space it requires, use -

```
<div id="trailerquestion" style="visibility:hidden">
```

If you want the div to not take up any space at all and be hidden, use -

```
<div id="trailerquestion" style="display:none">
```

Comment: I think you meant to say `visibility: hidden;` not `display: hidden;`. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Set the  element to be hidden with css e.g `<div id="trailerquestion" style="display:none">`

You might need to set it to display again when you show the dialog if your dialog library doesn't do that for you.